# Multidimensional array in numba njit function

Tags: python, arrays, types, numba

How to put multidimensional array into numba njit function?

example:

```
from numba import njit
import numpy as np

array =[
    [[0.0], [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]],
    [[4.0], [5.0, 6.0, 7.0]],
]

@njit
def show_array(arr):
    print(arr)

show_array(np.array(array))
```

Comment: `print` is not supported in `njit`. If you do other operations in the njit function it should be fine with multidimensional arrays

Comment: @mck may be print is not supported at earlier version of numba, but it works pretty well in version 0.51 if put to 'show_array'  this array: arr = np.array([(1, 2)], dtype=[('a1', 'f8'), ('a2', 'f8')]):